# Semantic UI Dropdown , trying to set state from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, semantic-ui, yarnpkg, react-dom

I am trying to render dropdown semantic component, 2 times in parent component by trying ternary operator in name filed and value field. This is my parent component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CountrySel from "./countrySelection";

class AppDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nationality1: "",
      nationality2: "",
    };
  }

  valueChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ApplicantDetail">
          <label>
            {" "}
            Nationality 1:
            <CountrySel
              name="nationality1"
              countrySelection={this.state.nationality1}
            />
          </label>
          <br></br>
          <label >
            {" "}
            Nationality 2:
            <CountrySel
              name="nationality2"
              countrySelection={this.state.nationality2}
            />
          </label>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppDetail;
```

*And my child component is* :-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

const countryOptions = [
  { key: "af", value: "af", flag: "af", text: "Afghanistan" },
  { key: "ax", value: "ax", flag: "ax", text: "Aland Islands" },
  { key: "al", value: "al", flag: "al", text: "Albania" },
  { key: "dz", value: "dz", flag: "dz", text: "Algeria" },
  { key: "as", value: "as", flag: "as", text: "American Samoa" },
  { key: "ad", value: "ad", flag: "ad", text: "Andorra" },
  { key: "ao", value: "ao", flag: "ao", text: "Angola" },
  { key: "ai", value: "ai", flag: "ai", text: "Anguilla" },
  { key: "ag", value: "ag", flag: "ag", text: "Antigua" },
  { key: "ar", value: "ar", flag: "ar", text: "Argentina" },
  { key: "am", value: "am", flag: "am", text: "Armenia" },
  { key: "aw", value: "aw", flag: "aw", text: "Aruba" },
  { key: "au", value: "au", flag: "au", text: "Australia" },
  { key: "at", value: "at", flag: "at", text: "Austria" },
  { key: "az", value: "az", flag: "az", text: "Azerbaijan" },
  { key: "bs", value: "bs", flag: "bs", text: "Bahamas" },
  { key: "bh", value: "bh", flag: "bh", text: "Bahrain" },
  { key: "bd", value: "bd", flag: "bd", text: "Bangladesh" },
  { key: "bb", value: "bb", flag: "bb", text: "Barbados" },
  { key: "by", value: "by", flag: "by", text: "Belarus" },
  { key: "be", value: "be", flag: "be", text: "Belgium" },
  { key: "bz", value: "bz", flag: "bz", text: "Belize" },
  { key: "bj", value: "bj", flag: "bj", text: "Benin" },
  { key: "uk", value: "uk", flag: "uk", text: "United Kingdom" },
  { key: "in", value: "in", flag: "in", text: "India" },
];

class countrySelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nationality1: " ",
      nationality2: " ",
    };
  }

  selectCountry = (val) => (
    <Dropdown
      placeholder="Select Country"
      fluid
      search
      selection
      value={this.props.nationality2}-->Here tried with ternary operator and in name field as well, but nothing works...
      options={countryOptions}
      onChange={this.handleDropdownChange.bind(this)}
    />
  );

  handleDropdownChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.selectCountry(this.props.countrySelection)}</div>;
  }
}

export default countrySelect;
```

Trying to acheive below functionality:-

when i select nationality1, my nationality1 state should be updated to the parent and for nationality 2 vice-versa.

Could anyone help me on this please ??...

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to send data from your child to your parent if I understand well. You can simply pass the `valueChange` method to your child component, it will call it when it's needed.

Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-uapopv?file=index.js) and here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [appState, setAppState] = React.useState(null);

  const valueChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    setAppState(prevState => ({...prevState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Child 1: <Child valueChange={valueChange} childName="child1" /> 
      <br />
      Child 2 :<Child valueChange={valueChange} childName="chlid2" />
      <br />
      <br />
      appState : <pre>{JSON.stringify(appState)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ valueChange, childName }) => {
  return <input type="text" name={childName} onChange={valueChange} />;
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

**[Edit]** Here is the version with class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = null;

  valueChange(e) {
    e.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Child 1: <Child valueChange={(e) => this.valueChange(e)} childName="child1" />
        <br />
        Child 2 :<Child valueChange={(e) => this.valueChange(e)} childName="chld2" />
        <br />
        <br />
        state : <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Child = ({ valueChange, childName }) => {
  return (
    <select name={childName} onChange={valueChange}>
    <option selected>None</option>
    <option value="nat 1">Nat 1</option>
    <option value="nat 2">Nat 2</option>
    <option value="nat 3">Nat 3</option>
  </select>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks Grisel, but i need my single dropdown works for both nationality 1 and nationality 2 component and for both state to be updated in my parent.

Comment: Well that's what my code do. There is only one ChildComponent with an input (change it with a dropdown if you want, that's the same thing), and it update the parent component when you write inside (same thing if you select somethign from a dropdown). If it's not what you want then rewrite your question to explain what you are trying to achieve please.

Comment: Tried as suggested buddy,modified the code as below , now getting undefined for name and value pair in console. Could you suggest without setAppState as i am getting error regarding Hooks(hooks not properly used or broken).

Comment: @RaviTejaLanda I edited my answer to give you the class component version of the code. I also replaced the input with a select since you are using it. Note that you can't use hooks in class component that's why you had error

Answer (score 0):

`````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

const countryOptions = [
  { key: "af", value: "af", flag: "af", text: "Afghanistan" },
  { key: "ax", value: "ax", flag: "ax", text: "Aland Islands" },
  { key: "al", value: "al", flag: "al", text: "Albania" },
  { key: "dz", value: "dz", flag: "dz", text: "Algeria" },
  { key: "as", value: "as", flag: "as", text: "American Samoa" },
  { key: "ad", value: "ad", flag: "ad", text: "Andorra" },
  { key: "ao", value: "ao", flag: "ao", text: "Angola" },
  { key: "ai", value: "ai", flag: "ai", text: "Anguilla" },
  { key: "ag", value: "ag", flag: "ag", text: "Antigua" },
  { key: "ar", value: "ar", flag: "ar", text: "Argentina" },
  { key: "am", value: "am", flag: "am", text: "Armenia" },
  { key: "aw", value: "aw", flag: "aw", text: "Aruba" },
  { key: "au", value: "au", flag: "au", text: "Australia" },
  { key: "at", value: "at", flag: "at", text: "Austria" },
  { key: "az", value: "az", flag: "az", text: "Azerbaijan" },
  { key: "bs", value: "bs", flag: "bs", text: "Bahamas" },
  { key: "bh", value: "bh", flag: "bh", text: "Bahrain" },
  { key: "bd", value: "bd", flag: "bd", text: "Bangladesh" },
  { key: "bb", value: "bb", flag: "bb", text: "Barbados" },
  { key: "by", value: "by", flag: "by", text: "Belarus" },
  { key: "be", value: "be", flag: "be", text: "Belgium" },
  { key: "bz", value: "bz", flag: "bz", text: "Belize" },
  { key: "bj", value: "bj", flag: "bj", text: "Benin" },
  { key: "uk", value: "uk", flag: "uk", text: "United Kingdom" },
  { key: "in", value: "in", flag: "in", text: "India" },
];

class countrySelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nationality1: " ",
      nationality2: " ",
    };
  }

  valueChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    if (e.target.name === "undefined") {
      return;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
      console.log(e.target.name);
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  selectCountry = ({ valueChange, childName }) => {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Country"
        name={childName}
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryOptions}
        onChange={valueChange}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Child 1:{" "}
        <this.selectCountry
          valueChange={this.valueChange}
          childName="nationality1"
        />
        <br />
        Child 2 :
        <this.selectCountry
          valueChange={this.valueChange}
          childName="nationality2"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default countrySelect;

````
`````